# How can I let tables be created automatically from entity classes with PostgreSQL and JPA?

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, jakarta-ee, persistence

I need to know whether automatic table creation is possible using PostgreSQL instead of Derby.

The story: I successfully set up a NetBeans Java project with Hibernate and Derby. I have created JPA controller classes from my entity classes. To test the project I created JUnit test classes for those controller classes.

When running those test classes for the first time, the tables will be automatically created in Derby. After executing the test, I can see the tables in the database browser.

In the persistence.xml there's a line like this

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/MySampleDb;create=true"/>
```

setting up the connection and indicating the tables to be created when needed (note the ";create=true" at the end of the line).

When using PostgreSQL instead of Derby. This doesn't work anymore. Adding ";create=true" breaks the code. Is this automatic table creation possible with PostgreSQL at all? Should I use a different persistence library other than Hibernate?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is possible. You need to set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` propery to `create`

```
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"/>
```